# How to add fragments to tabs in ViewPagerIndicator?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm following this library sample and using this library to create tabs in a ViewPager and add Fragments to them.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/SampleTabsDefault.java

Though I'm able to create the tabs, I'm not able to attach fragments to them. Any help?

Edit:

My tab activity looks something like this:

```
public class TabActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements StreamFragment.onStreamSelectedListener{
    TabHost mTabHost;
    TabManager mTabManager;
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
    Home f1;
    static FragmentTransaction ft;
    static View v;
    public static String currentFragment;


    @Override   
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);
        mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        bundle.putString("stream","sourceId"); 


        mTabManager = new TabManager(this, mTabHost, R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("Home"),
                        Home.class, null);
        mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("streams").setIndicator("Streams"),
                StreamFragment.class, null); 
        mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("source").setIndicator("Source"),
                SourceFragment.class, bundle); 
         f1 = (Home) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("home");

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
        }
    }
```

With a tabmanager declared that takes care of the tab switching and a onStreamSelectedListener which helps in connecting between tabs.

Now, when I try to implement using this:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ViewPager/VPI/src/com/commonsware/android/pager3/SampleAdapter.java

I'm a bit confused regarding where to load the fragments in the view and how to communicate in between them.

I tried doing something like this:

```
 @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if(position == 1)
          return(Home.newInstance(position));
    else if (position == 2)
           return(StreamFragment.newInstance(position));
  ....
  }
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right away to do this. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't "attach fragments to" tabs with ViewPagerIndicator. You populate a `ViewPager`, via a `PagerAdapter`, whether using fragments or something else. The contents of the `PagerAdapter`, in turn, will drive the contents of the tabs.

And, once GitHub is working again, you can take a look at [this sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/ViewPager/VPI) to see a working example of fragments in a `ViewPager`, with tabs supplied by `TabPagerIndicator` from the ViewPagerIndicator library.

Comment: How far backwards is this compatible? Does it support for phones less than 4.2?

Comment: @Hick: `ViewPager` works back to API Level 4. I do not recall off the top of my head how far back `TabPagerIndicator` works, but probably also to API Level 4. The backport of fragments works to API Level 4. My app happens to use ActionBarSherlock, which only supports back to API Level 7, but that is not required for this pattern in general.

Comment: So, what happens if I use this for phones that are still using 2.3 or versions older than 4.2? Crash?

Comment: @Hick: If you read my last comment, you will see that the relevant bits should work back to API Level 4, otherwise known as Android 1.6. Running the app on such devices will work fine. My *particular* sample *also* uses ActionBarSherlock, which limits you to Android 2.1 and higher.

Comment: Thank you so much. Also, I should have read this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html before posting a question. Though in place of a TabPagerIndicator, I presume they're using a ViewPagerListener.

Comment: @Hick: Actually, that sample is using action bar tabs.

Comment: @CommmonsWare I went through your tutorial but I'am a bit confused how to apply multiple fragments to it. I've edited my code to show where I'm getting stuck. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: @Hick: "But I'm not sure if this is the right away to do this" -- what you have should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help, as I've managed to implement it now.My only problem being tab switching which I was acomplishing via this code: http://pastebin.com/VBUCEeN5 I used to switch to tab 3 from tab 2, via onClick of Tab2. Now, I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

Comment: @Hick: Call `setCurrentItem()` on the `ViewPager`.

Comment: Fantastic! Any particular reason why tabs.setCurrentItem() didn't work? where tabs is the TabPageIndicator

Comment: @Hick: I did not write ViewPagerIndicator.